# Set autocomplete_easyadmin Select Null por defecto Symfony EasyAdmin Bundle

Tags: symfony2, symfony3, symfony, symfony4

Me gustaría saber si sabeis alguna forma de poner un valor *nulo* por *defecto* en el *select easyadmin_autocomplete*.

Aparece seleccionado el primer elemento del listado pero quiero que primero apunte a uno vacío (Elija uno).
¿Sabeis cómo hacerlo?
¿Se os ocurre alguna forma combinando las opciones definidas?

```
#easy_admin.yml
Product:
      class: App\Entity\Product
      controller: App\Controller\ProductController
      new:
        fields:
          - { property: 'category', label: 'Category', type: 'easyadmin_autocomplete', type_options: { class: 'App\Entity\Category' } }
 }
```

Estas son las opciones definidas para el attr *fields -> type_options* del *yml*:

1. action
2. allow_extra_fields
3. allow_file_upload
4. attr
5. auto_initialize
6. block_name
7. by_reference
8. class
9. compound
10. constraints
11. csrf_field_name
12. csrf_message
13. csrf_protection
14. csrf_token_id
15. csrf_token_manager
16. data
17. data_class
18. disabled
19. empty_data
20. error_bubbling
21. error_mapping
22. extra_fields_message
23. help
24. help_attr
25. inherit_data
26. invalid_message
27. invalid_message_parameters
28. label
29. label_attr
30. label_format
31. mapped
32. method
33. multiple
34. post_max_size_message
35. property_path
36. required
37. translation_domain
38. trim
39. upload_max_size_message
40. validation_groups